# UseEffect Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs

I have been working on a React Project and trying to add a Login feature has been causing me issues for days now. No matter what I have tried I continue getting errors and the most common being "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client". I feel like the UseEffect is causing it but I am then unsure how to actually log in. Any advice would help

```
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


function Home() {
    const [userNameLog, setuserNameLog] = useState('')
    const [passLog, setPasswordLog] = useState('')
    const [userName, setuserName] = useState('')
    const [pass, setPassword] = useState('')
    const [userDisplay, setUserDisplay] = useState([])



const login = () => {
    axios.post('http://localhost:8080/login', {
        username: userNameLog,
        password: passLog,
    }).then((response) => {
        if(response.data.message){
            setUserDisplay(response.data.message) 
        }else{
            setUserDisplay(response.data[0].username)
        }
    });
};

useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/login').then((response) => {
        if (response.data.loggedIn === true) {
            setUserDisplay(response.data.user[0].username);
        }
    })
}, [])

const register = () => {
    axios.post('http://localhost:8080/users/add', {
        username: userName,
        password: pass,
    }).then(() => {
        alert("Success!")
    });
};


return (
    <div className="home">
        {/* <AccountBox className="box"/> */}
        <div className="homecontent">
            <div className="form">
                <h1>Create User</h1>

                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Username..."
                required onChange={(e) => {setuserName(e.target.value)}} />

                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="text" name="Password" placeholder="Password..."
                required onChange={(e) => {setPassword(e.target.value)}} />

                <button onClick={register}>Submit</button>
            </div>

            <div className="form">
                <h1>Login</h1>

                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Username..."
                required onChange={(e) => {setuserNameLog(e.target.value)}} />

                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="text" name="Password" placeholder="Password..." 
                required onChange={(e) => {setPasswordLog(e.target.value)}} />
                
                <button onClick={login}>Login</button>
            </div>
            {userDisplay.map((val) => {
                        return <h1>ID: {val.id} | Username: {val.username} | Password: {val.password} | User Type: {val.userType}</h1>
                    })}
        </div>
    </div>
);
}

export default Home;
```

Here is the Server Side code:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();

//Allow user to stay logged in while changing tabs
const session = require("express-session")
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const saltRounds = 10;
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
var database = require('./database.js');
database.openDB();

var writer = require('./writer.js');
app.use('/', writer);
app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.use(session({
        key: "userId",
        secret: "eliReview",
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        cookie: {
            expires: 60 * 60 *24,
        },
    })
)

const db = database.getDB()

// User registration
app.post('/users/add', (req, res) =>{
    console.log("Got User")
    if(req.body && req.body.username && req.body.password){
        const username = req.body.username
        const password = req.body.password
        bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, (err, hash) => {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
            }
            const sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO user (username, password) VALUES ( (?), (?) )"
            db.all(sqlInsert, [username, password], (err, result)=> {
                if (err) {
                    res.sendStatus(400);
                    // console.log(err.message);
                }
                else {
                    if(!result) {
                        res.sendStatus(404);
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log(result);
                        res.json(result);
                    }
                }
            })
        })
    }
});

// Get all users
app.get('/users/get', (req, res) =>{
    const sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM user;"
    db.all(sqlQuery, (err, result)=> {
        if (err) {
            res.sendStatus(400);
            console.log(err.message);
        }
        else {
            if(!result) {
                res.sendStatus(404);
            }
            else {
                // console.log(result);
                res.json(result);
            }
        }
    })
    
});

// User Login
app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
    const username = req.body.username;
    const password = req.body.password;
    db.all(
      "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?;",
      username,
      (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          res.send({ err: err });
        }
        console.log("Here")
  
        if (result) {
            console.log("Here2")
            bcrypt.compare(password, result[0].password, ( error, response) => {
                if(response){
                    console.log("Here3")
                    req.session.user = result
                    console.log(req.session.user)
                    res.send(result)
                }else{
                    res.send({message: "Wrong username/password combination!"})
                }
            })
        }else{
            // req.session.user = result
            // console.log(req.session.user)
            console.log("Got Here")
            res.send({ message: "User doesn't exist"})
            // res.json(result);
            
        }
      }
    );
  });

app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
    if (req.session.user) {
        res.send({ loggedIn: true, user: req.session.user });
    } else {
        res.send({ loggedIn: false });
    }
});
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});
```

Comment: The problem  is in server side inside user login inside if(err) use return keyword to send error response .the reason behind it is a error has occurred and it already send response but after checking result parameter it became false so again it send response "wrong username " so sending response twice is causing this error .so I recommend to use "return" keyword while sending response so that function execution ends

Comment: @JagadishShrestha So I returned all my responses in my /login but it did not change anything I am still crashing and getting the same error